Removing a window and door and replacing with one large slider
I have a nine-foot slider I would like to put in place of a large window and single French door.  Above both were headers same level.  In between the two headers is one 2x4 floor to higher up beam. There were at least two more 2x4 originally.  One on each side of the one that is still there.  In order for this header to be one I am trying to find the least damaging way to replace the two with one header or add some steel support to be as strong as one. Choices appear to be a custom c section channel or a flitch beam/plate. From what I am reading it can be used to put LVLs together but there are also other structural strengthening type of installs.  Suggestions?

Suggestions? ... yes ... ask at https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions
